# Using fscanf to read a string and then a variable number of integers to EOF

Tags: c, integer, eof, scanf

I'm having a little trouble starting a project I have been assigned. I can't use string operators, `fgets`, etc. I need to scan a file to EOF.

Here is an example of the file:

```
AND 3 2 1
OR 4 5 6
SPECIAL 4 5 6 7
```

What I tried to do is set up a while loop:

```
while (fscanf(circuit, "%s", cur_gate) != EOF){
```

then tried to check what the cur_gate string is:

```
if (cur_gate[0] == 'A'){
```

The problem is, I don't know how I would scan 3 integers after reading the string. Then eventually, once it reads SPECIAL, I need to scan 4 integers.

I want to store the first integer in a array called Output, and the rest in an array called INPUT.

So to summarize, how would I fscanf a string and then fscanf a variable amount of integers depending on the string I have read?

Comment: You could fscanf the string, and then see what the string is and then read the right number of numbers according to what the string is

Comment: What have you tried? Its a bonus to do this by yourself, using tutorials without asking us. You should get the classic K&R book on C that will answer most of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sound to me like you're supposed to use `fgetc` and parse the file yourself.

Comment: Ive tried to do many things, so i made it very basic to try and firgure it out, this did not work:
 
'while(fscanf(circuit, "%s", cur_gate)!=EOF){
        if(cur_gate[0] == 'A'){
                fscanf(circuit,"%d",output[0]);
                printf("%d",output[0]);'

Comment: I figured it out, I thought you weren't suppose to use "&" when you fscanf something into an array. Thanks guys!

Comment: You don't need the `&` when you are passing a `char *` for use with `%s`.  In most other circumstances, you need an `&`.  When you're scanning three (or four) integers, you aren't dealing with an array; you're dealing with three (or four) separate integers, that happen to be elements of an array.  Just as you might use `&x, &y, &z`, so too would you use `&output[0], &output[1], &output[2]`.

Comment: Post the definition of `cur_gate`.  A good answer depends on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your question, below code would help you.

I assumed, that you just wanted to store all the outputs in just one array, and similarly all the inputs in one array. So, as per your example you want to store 3,4,4 (first integer just after word) in output array. Rest of the integers need to go to another input array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CHAR  256
#define MAX_IN    100
#define MAX_OUT   100

enum
{
    FALSE = 0,
    TRUE
};

int main()
{
    char word[MAX_CHAR];
    FILE *fp;

    int i = 0, in[MAX_IN];
    int o = 0, out[MAX_OUT];

    int flag = FALSE;

    fp = fopen("dict.txt","r");
    if(NULL != fp)
    {
        while(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            printf("%s\n",word);
            if(0 != isalpha(word[0]))
            {
                flag = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                if(TRUE == flag)
                {
                    out[o] = atoi(word);
                    o++;
                    flag = FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    in[i] = atoi(word);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    int j;
    printf("INPUT: ");
    for(j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",in[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("OUTPUT: ");
    for(j=0; j<o; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",out[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

OUTPUT for the example of file you have given

```
INPUT: 2        1       5       6       5       6       7
OUTPUT: 3       4       4
```

**DISCLAIMER: The code has been compiled and tested in my environment. I encourage you to take care of error handling scenarios  yourself.**

Comment: if the call to `fopen()` fails, the code is still going to try to print from the arrays, but the contents of the arrays will be garbage.

Comment: regarding this line: `while(fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF)`  when calling the function: `fscanf()`, the best way to exit the loop, that takes into account all posibilites is to compare with (in this case) ==1.   Then have an inner loop that reads the numeric values.

Comment: the posted answer does not compile, because the statement: `#include <ctype.h> is missing, so the `isalpha()` function is not prototyped

Comment: @user3629249. I am not sure how and why but my compiler is intelligent enough to compile the same program and produced the desired output as I've pasted.

Comment: Sure, it will compile.  And  since the default values are usable, it will even (mostly) run correctly.   However, If your not seeing any warnings, then your not enabling the warnings.  For gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @user3629249, yeah I agree.....I generally compile question posted on SO without any option. That's the reason, I didn't get any warnings. Thanks for reminding me.